# Integrating 2 authentication windows to a single window.: JAVA Authentication with network

Tags: java, javascript, xml, authentication, network-protocols

There is an issue of java authentication with network.

when we connect to our java platform interior through some website, it asks for 2 authentications as also shown in the images attached

1. authentication(windows) for server at port 8401  (port 8401)
2. java authentication abc.sdf.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:8100  (port 8100)

both have same user IDs,

source: ABC.com:8401/ ? Dispatched=//ABC.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:8100

I believe many people would have resolved this kind of issue in their projects. 
Can anyone please consult some ideas/ways in order to achieve a single Authentication window????

Thanks in advance